# Get Billing Agreements For Test Accounts

Tags: paypal

We are setting up new PayPal integration, and I am having some trouble getting the Billing Agreements.  Here is our scenario:

- Third party captures payment authorization
- Third party sends us the Billing Agreement ID (they call it a Transaction Number)
- We do a reference transaction to execute the payment, using that ID (this is done to renew a subscription, typically every 30 days or so)

What I am trying to do is actually write that third part.  However, first it must be tested, and I am having trouble getting the billing agreement ID's for my test accounts.  I assume that typically that part is handled through a web page that the customer has signed in to with PayPal, so the API knows what purchaser account is being linked.  How do I do this programmatically?  Or manually?  I don't care, because we will never be making this call, I just need the ID's for the test accounts.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Express Checkout.  When you call SetExpressCheckout just make sure to include the billing agreement parameters.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I added those calls in there, but I get an error return:

"You do not have permissions to make this API call"

I think I recall needing to get something turned on?  Do I just contact PayPal support?

Comment: Okay, now I put in the right credentials and signature (I swear they weren't in the facilitator account profile a few minutes ago) and I get a more descriptive "Merchant not enabled for reference transactions".  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yup, just need to get that enabled on your account and you'll be ready to rock!